# How to allow moving the cursor while typing with xserver-xorg-input-libinput installed?

Tags: gnome, configuration, customization, cursor

Since I installed `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`, although it fixed my other problems, it has meant that I am unable to move my cursor while typing. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20, is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `DisableWhileTyping` option in `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` is enabled by default, in order to disable it and be allowed to move the cursor while typing simply create a directory within `/etc/X11` called `xorg.conf.d`, within that create a config file called `99-libinput-disable-dwt.conf`, the make this its contents:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "Disable DWT"
   MatchDriver "libinput"
   Option "DisableWhileTyping" "off"
EndSection
```

Then restart X. You may also set it at runtime with:

```
xinput set-prop "device name" "property name" 0
```